# Как сделать два slick slider на одном сайте?

Tags: slider-slick.js

Есть два слайдера, в данный момент при нажатии одной из стрелок работают одновременно, как мне это исправить? Классы меня не хочу)

```js
    $('.my-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-b',
    variableWidth: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
});
    
    
$('.slider-b').slick({
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    asNavFor: '.my-slider',
});


    $('.my-slider').on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    var totalPages = Math.ceil(slick.slideCount / slick.originalSettings.slidesToScroll);
    var currentPage = Math.ceil((currentSlide + 1) / slick.originalSettings.slidesToScroll);
    counter.innerText =  currentPage + '/' + totalPages;
});
```

```css
/* normalize */

* {
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Atmospheric';
    color: var(--white);
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

li{
    list-style: none;
}

.wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.my-container{
    max-width: 1236px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: auto;
}

.main{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

/* slider */
.slider{
    position: relative;
}

.slick-list{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slick-track {
    display: flex;
}

.slick-slide {
    width: 114px;
}

.slick-arrow{
    position: absolute;
    top: 93px;
    z-index: 10;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border: 0;
}

.slick-prev{
    left: 74px;
}

.slick-next{
    right: 74px;
}
/*  */

.container{
    width: 333px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.sec-slider{
    background: url('../img/games.jpg') 35% 50% no-repeat;
    height: 812px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 82px;
}

.sec-slider__flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.sec-slider__h2{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.my-slider,
.my-slider2{
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 302px;
    margin-bottom: 29px;
}

.slider-b,
.slider-b2{
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 302px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.slider-b__img{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slider-b__img img{
    width: 144px;
    height: 144px;
}

.slider-b__name {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.slider-b__info{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 95px;
}

.slider-b__socials{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.slider-b__socials img{
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.slider-b__socials img:last-child{
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>INJFanZone</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
       <section class="sec-slider games">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="sec-slider__flex">
              <h2 class="sec-slider__h2">Games</h2>

              <div class="slider-b">
                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b__img">
                    <img src="img/blaze.svg" alt="" />
                  </div>
                  <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                  <p class="slider-b__info">
                    Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                    revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                    transparency and integrity for players.
                  </p>
                  <div class="slider-b__socials">
                    <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                    <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/blaze.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/blaze.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/blaze.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/blaze.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/blaze.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/blaze.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/blaze.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/blaze.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="my-slider">
                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/blaze.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/octos-xenzia.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/gf.svg" alt="" />
                </div>

                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/blaze.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/octos-xenzia.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/gf.svg" alt="" />
                </div>

                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/blaze.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/octos-xenzia.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/gf.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <output class="counter"></output>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section class="sec-slider nft">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="sec-slider__flex">
              <h2 class="sec-slider__h2">NFTs</h2>

              <div class="slider-b">
                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b__img">
                    <img src="img/astroud-b.svg" alt="" />
                  </div>
                  <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                  <p class="slider-b__info">
                    Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                    revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                    transparency and integrity for players.
                  </p>
                  <div class="slider-b__socials">
                    <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                    <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/astroud-b.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/astroud-b.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/astroud-b.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/astroud-b.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/astroud-b.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/astroud-b.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/astroud-b.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-b-item">
                  <div class="slider-b-item">
                    <div class="slider-b__img">
                      <img src="img/astroud-b.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="slider-b__name">Ninja Blaze</p>
                    <p class="slider-b__info">
                      Ninja Blaze is a blockchain-enabled gaming platform that
                      revolutionizes the marketplace and provides complete
                      transparency and integrity for players.
                    </p>
                    <div class="slider-b__socials">
                      <img src="img/twittre.svg" alt="" />
                      <img src="img/ds.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="my-slider">
                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/astroud.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/bisy.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/orbits.svg" alt="" />
                </div>

                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/astroud.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/bisy.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/orbits.svg" alt="" />
                </div>

                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/astroud.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/bisy.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="my-slider-item">
                  <img src="img/orbits.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <output class="counter"></output>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>

      <!-- footer -->
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы слайдеры работали независимо друг от друга и не синхронизировались, нужно изменить настройки asNavFor и удалить его из одного из слайдеров. У тебя в коде  есть два слайдера, .my-slider и .slider-b, которые синхронизированы с помощью asNavFor. Чтобы отменить синхронизацию, нужно удалить asNavFor из одного из них.

Вот как будет выглядеть код после удаления asNavFor из .my-slider:

```
    $('.my-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
});


$('.slider-b').slick({
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
});
```

Теперь .my-slider и .slider-b будут работать независимо друг от друга, и при нажатии стрелок они не будут взаимодействовать друг с другом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, мне нужно отвязать не .slider-b, а .my-slider (их там два)

Answer (score 0):

Тогда оставляй asNavFor только для одного из них.

```
    $('.my-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    asNavFor: '.slider-b', // Оставьте синхронизацию только с .slider-b
});


$('.my-slider2').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    // Не указывайте asNavFor здесь, чтобы отвязать от синхронизации
});

$('.slider-b').slick({
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    asNavFor: '.my-slider', // Сохраните синхронизацию только с .my-slider
});
```